# ScrollMagic & TweenMax Adding Scenes

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

my Javascript knowledge is very limited. I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLUJ9VNzZXo

and all is working as described in video. He cuts off at the "add more text animations" at the end and this is where I'm struggling. I can't get the extra text animations to work. Here is what I have: (the piece I've added is contained between the //Added By Me comment:

```js
const intro = document.querySelector('.intro');
const video = intro.querySelector('video');
const text = intro.querySelector('h1');

const section = document.querySelector('section');
const end = section.querySelector('h1');

const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 8000,
    triggerElement: intro,
    triggerHook: 0
})
    //.addIndicators() <-- add this in if you want to see the Animation triggers on the screen
    .setPin(intro)
    .addTo(controller);

//text Animation
const textAnim = TweenMax.fromTo(text, 2, { opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 });
const textAnim2 = TweenMax.fromTo(end, 4, { opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 });

let scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 3000,
    triggerElement: intro,
    triggerHook: 0
})
    .setTween(textAnim)
    .addTo(controller);

//Added by Me
let scene3 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 3000,
    triggerElement: intro,
    triggerHook: 0
})
    .setTween(textAnim2)
    .addTo(controller);
//End Added By Me

//video animation
let accelamount = 0.1;
let scrollpos = 0;
let delay = 0;

scene.on('update', e => {
    scrollpos = e.scrollPos/50;
})

setInterval(() => {
    delay = (scrollpos - delay) * accelamount;
    video.currentTime = delay;
}, 40
);
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'
}

.intro {
    height: 100vh;
}

    .intro video {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .intro h1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        font-size: 4em;
        color: white;
    }

section h1 {
    padding-top: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ssMainVid.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="intro">
        <h1>Revolutionary Socks</h1>
        <video src="images/SampleVid.mp4"></video>
    </div>
    <section>
        <h1>Another Heading</h1>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/ScrollMagic.min.js" integrity="sha512-8E3KZoPoZCD+1dgfqhPbejQBnQfBXe8FuwL4z/c8sTrgeDMFEnoyTlH3obB4/fV+6Sg0a0XF+L/6xS4Xx1fUEg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-5/OHwmQzDSBS0Ous4/hlYoWLHd06/d2r7LdKZQVBXOA6PvOqWVXtdboiLTU7lQTGyVoKVTNkwi0ol4gHGlw5ww==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js" integrity="sha512-mq6TSOBEH8eoYFBvyDQOQf63xgTeAk7ps+MHGLWZ6Byz0BqQzrP+3GIgYL+KvLaWgpL8XgDVbIRYQeLa3Vqu6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-DkPsH9LzNzZaZjCszwKrooKwgjArJDiEjA5tTgr3YX4E6TYv93ICS8T41yFHJnnSmGpnf0Mvb5NhScYbwvhn2w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is add text will display/ hide based on the scroll position on the screen. The first ones works fine but not the subsequent one.

Comment: Anyone any ideas??

Comment: Anyone any ideas?